# Making Iphone App Working on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.2

I have created an iPhone Application, which works only on iPhone.

Now, I want that App on iPad, too.

Is there any way that I can reuse my existing iPhone XIBs to support that App on iPad. (I don't want to recreate all the XIBs for iPad separately.)

Any guidance for that?

Also, What other points I need to take care of?

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone app will work in iPad if you choose 2x zoom view. But the display will not be of the highest quality. Now rumors are there that next iPad will have retina display. So, one suggestion I can give is, when you create a new project, Choose "Universal" as the option for device family.

Depending on your app, Feature detection might be one thing you have to look out for when you try to run an app on iPad. For example, Siri is available for iPhone 4s, but not iPad 2. (Although the API for Siri isn't out yet, I'm just putting it there). Also, iPhone 4 has camera, while iPad 1 doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your target, and under "Devices" change to Universal. Now your project should run on either device.